# RubyMine sort db/migrate filenames

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rubymine

RubyMine Project View: is there any way to sort the filenames in reverse order? Specifically the `db/migrate` folder. It would be nice to have the most recent migration at the top of the list instead of having to scroll to the bottom of a list of hundreds. I see a "Sort by Type" setting, but that doesn't help in this case.

I did find a comment from JetBrains (dated 2012) to the effect of "we can't imagine why you would want to change the sort order", so I guess it's probably not possible, but maybe someone here knows of a trick or plugin or something.

Comment: A co-worker notes that migrations can be organized into subfolders, which doesn't completely solve the problem, but it does make it more manageable. I'll probably do that, but I'd like to leave the question open in case somebody has an even better solution.

Comment: In RubyMine it's indeed not supported yet but there's a corresponding request so you can add your vote there: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125956